# Looping through the subfolders of a given folder and append the folder name with Date upon condition

Tags: batch-file

I am new in windows batch scripting and would like to ask the following question:

Suppose I have "xyz" folder which contains several other subfolders. Now I want to loop through these subfolders and if any of them has a specific name (say "abc") then I would rename it with current date (like "abc_ddmmyy") and store it to some other folder. 
How this can be done using a MS-DOS batch file?

Comment: Only one file can have that `"abc_ddmmyy"` name so you will need to say if there will be other `abc` files.

Comment: use "for" for the loop, "if" for the comparison and "%date% and "move" to move folders around. please read at least the descriptions of those commands and start to put together a script. we might be able to help you then. i don't think anyone will just create that script for you and post a tested and ready version here....